# Printing objects by category

Tags: python

I have a problem which I do not know how to solve. I want that I could print objects by its category. For example, I want to see only footwear objects and etc. What method I should create? I hope you understood what I am asking for if not feel free to ask.

Here is my code:

```
class Item: 
    name = ""
    price = ""
    size = ""
    additionalInfo = ""
    forWhichSex= ""
    itemType= ""

    def __init__(self, name, price, size, additionalInfo, forWhichSex, itemType):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price 
        self.size = size
        self.additionalInfo = additionalInfo
        self.forWhichSex = forWhichSex
        self.itemType = itemType

    @staticmethod
    def createItemWithCategory(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType):
        if FootWear.isFootWear(itemType):
            return FootWear(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType)
        elif Appearel.isAppearel(itemType):
            return Appearel(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType)
        elif Accessory.isAccessory(itemType):
            return Accessory(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType)
        else:
            return None

class FootWear(Item):   
    def __init__(self,name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType):
        super().__init__(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType)   

    @staticmethod
    def isFootWear(itemType):
        defaultCategory = ["lifestyle shoes", "basketball shoes", "training shoes","running shoes","tennis shoes","soccer shoes","slides shoes"]
        for dcategory in defaultCategory:
            if dcategory in itemType.lower():
                return True
        return False

class Appearel(Item):
    def __init__(self,name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType):
        super().__init__(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex,itemType)

    @staticmethod
    def isAppearel(itemType):
        defaultCategory = ["shirts", "jackets", "hoodies","pants", "shorts", "bathrobes", "bra", "skirts/dresses", "vests"]
        for dcategory in defaultCategory:
            if dcategory in itemType.lower():
                return True
        return False

class Accessory(Item):
    def __init__(self,name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex):
        super().__init__(name,price,size,additionalInfo,forWhichSex)   

    @staticmethod
    def isAccessory(itemType):
        defaultCategory = ["caps", "wristbands", "backpacks", "socks", "balls", "shoelaces", "watches", "scarves", "gloves", "towels", "flasks", "braces"]
        for dcategory in defaultCategory:
            if dcategory in itemType.lower():
                return True
        return False
```

Reading from file json and printing looks like :

```
@staticmethod
def jsonOpener(jsonFileName):
    myItemList = []
    with open(jsonFileName, "r") as filelines:
        for fileline in filelines:
            jsonObj = json.loads(fileline)
            print(str(jsonObj))
            myItem = Item.createItemWithCategory(
                                            jsonObj['name'], 
                                            jsonObj['price'],
                                            jsonObj['size'],
                                            jsonObj['additionalInfo'],
                                            jsonObj['forWhichSex'],
                                            jsonObj['itemType']
                                                )
            print(type(myItem))                                    
            myItemList.append(myItem)
    return myItemList
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension and use `FootWear.isFootWear()` static method. Creates a list of item from the `itemList` list and get the ones that return `True` when calling your function.

```
listOfFootwearItems = [item for item in itemList if FootWear.isFootWear(item["itemType"])]
```

**EDIT:**

For instance, If you want you could have a function like this:

```
def filter_by_category(itemList, categoryFunction):
    return [item for item in itemList if categoryFunction(item["itemType"])]
```

And you can call it like this:

```
a = {"itemType" : "running shoes", "key": 1}
b = {"itemType" : "shirts", "key": 2}
c = {"itemType" : "wristbands", "key": 3}
d = {"itemType" : "running shoes", "key": 4}

l = [a, b, c, d]

footWears = filter_by_category(l, FootWear.isFootWear)
apparels = filter_by_category(l, Appearel.isAppearel)
accessories = filter_by_category(l, Accessory.isAccessory)
```

Note you are passing the static functions as an argument, remember functions in python are first-class citizens hence can be passed as arguments. If you print this result lists:

```
print(footWears)
print(apparels)
print(accessories)
```

**Outputs:**

```
[{'itemType': 'running shoes', 'key': 1}, {'itemType': 'running shoes', 'key': 4}]
[{'itemType': 'shirts', 'key': 2}]
[{'itemType': 'wristbands', 'key': 3}]
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, but I did not get you. Where should I write this ?

Comment: You should use it wherever you want to get the items based on that condition. I don't know where do you want to get them